# Still can't use a function defined in a separate .cpp file

Tags: c++, function, class, header-files

I've been searching through questions on this for hours, and it just isn't working for some reason, so sorry if there's already an answer and I just didn't understand it.

I'm doing a course on C++, and I've gotten to classes. As practice, he started by just calling a simple function that was defined in a separate .cpp file to show how a class would work later on. See code below:

```
//main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "Cat.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {
    speak();
    return 0;
}
```

============================

```
//Cat.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "Cat.h"
using namespace std;

void speak() {
    cout << "Meow" << endl;
}
```

================================

```
//Cat.h
#ifndef CAT_H_
#define CAT_H_

void speak();

#endif //CAT_H_
```

I've triple checked everything I could think of. They're in the same directory and I'm cross-referencing everything exactly as he did. I expect it to output "Meow" in the console, but if I call the speak() function in main.cpp, I still just get an empty function, despite it being defined in class.cpp. I don't know what I'm missing, and it's quite frustrating. Is is because of my compiler? I'm using Visual Studio IDE.

Edits: Used the wrong commented name

I'm using the built-in Visual Studio IDE's "Build" and "Compile" options. I'm not running the compilation using Linux commands or anything else.

@273K Here is the screenshot of my 3 VS files:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tbw8.png

Comment: The program works [here](https://onlinegdb.com/QlvmIGMA0). Make sure you've named your files correctly. In particular you are including `Cat.h` but have named your header `class.h`.

Comment: How are you compiling? Are there any compiler/linker errors?

Comment: The problem isn't the code. Are you building this or asking Visual Studio to run it? Does VS know about both files?

Comment: The last file should be named `Cat.h` but your comment indicates that it is named `class.h`. What does "_I still just get an empty function,_" mean? Please always add complete error messages or output of the program to the question.

Comment: Sorry, I had put the class.h and class.cpp comment name just to differentiate them better. They are named correctly in the program. I'll edit it.

Comment: @JosephLarson There aren't any compiler/linker errors like Johnny said. I tried building the project and running it, as well as compiling the two source files separately, as well as a combination of the two.

Comment: What does "I still just get an empty function" mean? How do you run your exe? You might run some another exe, not the newly compiled.

Comment: @273K when I run the project, it outputs nothing to the console, instead of outputting "meow" as expected. I'm running it using built in Visual Studio "Start Debugging" button. I don't know how I'd be running another .exe when I'm running it straight through VS

Comment: Please show the screenshot of VS. Drag all files for getting all files open and visible in VS window horizontally.

Comment: @273K Screenshot posted as edit in post

Comment: Look at the left side. The active project is BasicsOfC++. You run this protect and get the empty output. And look at the bottom: BasicsOfC++.exe has exited.

Comment: @273K Oh my god, thank you. If I right-click "ObjectOrientedCode" and Debug from there, it works. Is there a way to change the active project?

Comment: In the same context menu look for something like "Set as startup project".

Comment: @273K Thanks so much. I'll set that as an answer to the thread

Answer (score 2):

The **problem** is that you are including `Cat.h` but named your header `class.h` instead of `Cat.h`.

To solve this rename the files from `class.h` and `class.cpp` to `Cat.h` and `Cat.cpp` respectively, as shown below

**Cat.h**

```
#ifndef CAT_H_
#define CAT_H_

void speak();

#endif //CAT_H_
```

**Cat.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Cat.h"
using namespace std;

void speak() {
    cout << "Meow" << endl;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Cat.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {
    speak();
    return 0;
}
```

[Working demo](https://onlinegdb.com/WZPQKpR7e-)

Comment: Yeah, I put the wrong comment name. They're named the same as yours in the project, but it still didn't work. I think it's the compiler, like someone else said.

Comment: @JaydeNpie How are you compiling your code? Which command do you use. Make sure you're providing `Cat.cpp` when compiling the code.

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio's IDE, so I was compiling them together by highlighting all of them and using the built-in "Build > Compile" option, like the tutorial did.

Comment: In Visual Studio, you need to create a project, then add the .cpp files to the project, then compile the project.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes, they're already in the same project. Compiling the entire project was what I did first, then I tried compiling each .cpp separately within the project

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @273K for the solution:

In the screenshot, the wrong project was "selected" in the solution explorer, so it was running the wrong project code.

I fixed it by right-clicking the project I wanted and clicking "Set as StartUp Project"

Before: https://i.stack.imgur.com/na0nF.png

After: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJMLq.png